# Meta Pixel with GTM - Advanced matching parameters not sending

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I have sent up several standard events for meta pixel and implemented with google tag manager. within the preview window, meta pixel helper shows all parameters including the advanced matching parameters sending as they should. However when I submit, publish and test the tags on the live site, meta pixel helper shows the advanced matching parameters are missing.
[Screenshot of meta pixel helper from within GTM preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bERo3.png)

[Screenshot of meta pixel helper for same page on live site with missing advanced matching parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDg0q.png).

My initial thought was that the userData event wasn't being pushed to data layer early enough. But it sounds to me that it just needs to be before gtm.load which it is.
[console.log of data layer on site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTmsf.png).

I followed this [guide](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/facebook-pixel-with-google-tag-manager/) to set up (specifically section 6.3 - Advanced Matching)

I have enabled advanced matching on my base tracking page view tag, with the firing trigger set to dom ready and the variables linked up. As I mentioned all works as expected in preview mode but not on live.

Any advice would be appreciated, and just let me know if any more information from me would make this easier to answer.

Thanks!
Jacob

Comment: It will depend on when the page_view fired for Meta pixel. Usually the `userData` datalayer should be earlier then `gtm.js`